# What can I change so I can pull player and userOnline into my for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I would like to be able to print "player's status is userOnline" but it says that player and userOnline are not defined and I don't really know what to change around so it will work.

```
import requests, json

with open('key.txt','r') as api_key:
    key = api_key.readline()

with open('steam_ids.txt', 'r') as steam_ids:
    steam_id = steam_ids.readlines()
        

def username():
    username = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=%s&steamids=%s' % (key,steam)
    name = requests.get(username)
    nameResponse = name.json()
    nameResponseMain = nameResponse['response']
    player = nameResponseMain['players']
    player = player[0]['personaname']

def game():
    userOnline = False
    gameUrl = 'http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetRecentlyPlayedGames/v0001/?key=%s&steamid=%s&format=json' % (key,steam)
    currentGame = requests.get(gameUrl)
    gameResponse = currentGame.json()
    gameResponseMain = gameResponse['response']
    game = gameResponseMain['games']
    game = game[0]['name']
    if game == "Source SDK Base 2007":
        userOnline = True
    if userOnline == True:
        userOnline = "Online"
    else:
        userOnline = "Offline"

for steam in steam_id:
    username()
    game()
    print(player + '\'s status is ' + userOnline)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
    def username():
        ...
        return player
  
    def game():
        ...
        return userOnline

    for steam in steam_id:
        player = username()
        userOnline = game()
        print(f"{player}'s status is {userOnline}")
```